# How can I control the flow correctly in the subFlowMapping

Tags: spring-integration

This is the basic question but nowhere to ask. (I just started the spring-integration last Thursday.)
I have to use subFlowMapping. A single XML file can contain multiple domain data. The file name base filtering only tells me what kind of data contains in the XML file.

This is the working version. 2 persistent channels are well-executed and saves the data.

`channel("updatingPartsInventoryFlow.input")`

`channel("updatingTransactionCompleteLogFlow.input")`

```
.subFlowMapping(PayloadType.STOCK, sf -> sf
                    .transform(unmarshallingTransformer)
                    .<Stock, List<PartsInventory>>transform(s -> createPartsInventories(s))
                    .publishSubscribeChannel(c1 -> c1
                        .subscribe(s1 -> s1
                            .channel("updatingPartsInventoryFlow.input")))
                            .publishSubscribeChannel(c2 -> c2
                        .subscribe(s2 -> s2
                            .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                                return createPartsInventoryTransactionLog((List<PartsInventory>) payload,                                                   (String) headers.get("StartTime"));
                            })
                            .channel("updatingTransactionCompleteLogFlow.input"))))
```

These are not working well.

`channel("updatingPartsInventoryFlow.input")` *Data not saved always*

`channel("updatingTransactionCompleteLogFlow.input")`*Log saved always*

```
.subFlowMapping(PayloadType.STOCK, sf -> sf
                    .transform(unmarshallingTransformer)
                    .<Stock, List<PartsInventory>>transform(s -> createPartsInventories(s))
                    .channel("updatingPartsInventoryFlow.input")
                    .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                        return createPartsInventoryTransactionLog((List<PartsInventory>) payload, 
                                (String) headers.get("StartTime"));
                    })
                    .channel("updatingTransactionCompleteLogFlow.input"))

.subFlowMapping(PayloadType.STOCK, sf -> sf
                    .publishSubscribeChannel(c1 -> c1
                    .subscribe(s1 -> s1
                        .transform(unmarshallingTransformer)
                        .<Stock, List<PartsInventory>>transform(s -> createPartsInventories(s))
                        .channel("updatingPartsInventoryFlow.input")))
                        .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                            return createPartsInventoryTransactionLog((List<PartsInventory>) payload, 
                                            (String) headers.get("StartTime"));
                        })
                        .channel("updatingTransactionCompleteLogFlow.input"))))
```

Actually, my intention is not working versions. Data should be saved before the log.
The working version seems data and log are saving concurrently.
Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a several mapping entries for the same key. When you tell `.subFlowMapping(PayloadType.STOCK`, that means some internal channel is mapped to this type into a `HashMap`. That's how the second mapping for the same key always wins. So, your first solution is a correct way: one mapping for the expected type and `PublishSubscribeChannel` for distribution the same message to different sub-flows.